# How to retrieve the string value of a custom C# resource class constant?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created the following custom ValidationAttribute:

```
public class DateRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable {
  public DateTime MinimumDate = new DateTime(1901, 1, 1);
  public DateTime MaximumDate = new DateTime(2099, 12, 31);

   public DateRangeAttribute(string minDate, string maxDate, string errorMessage) {
     MinimumDate = DateTime.Parse(minDate);
     MaximumDate = DateTime.Parse(maxDate);
     ErrorMessage = string.Format(errorMessage, MinimumDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), MaximumDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
   }
}
```

that I would like to use in my MVC4 view model as follows:

```
[DateRange(Resources.MinimumDate, Resources.MaximumDate, "Please enter a date between {0} and {1}")]
```

*Resources* is a generated resources class based on a set of options stored in a SQL database.  A simplified version of the generated code for the above two resource properties is:

```
public class Resources {
  public const string MinimumDate = "PropMinimumDate";
  public static string PropMinimumDate
  {
     get { return "12/15/2010" } 
  }
  public const string MaximumDate = "PropMaximumDate";
  public static string PropMaximumDate
  {
     get { return "12/15/2012" } 
  }
}
```

While I do not understand how it works, I do understand that typical usage of resources in ValidationAttributes will automatically map *Resources.MinimumDate* to *PropMinimumDate* and return the value "12/15/2010".

What I am cannot figure out is how to manually make that programmatic leap myself so I can pass in the two date values into my custom ValidatorAttribute.  As presently coded, *"PropMinimumDate"* and *"PropMaximumDate"* are the *minDate* and *maxDate* parameter values (respectively) passed into the constructor of the DateRangeAttribute.

If I try

```
[DateRange(Resources.PropMinimumDate, Resources.PropMaximumDate, "Please enter a date between {0} and {1}")]
```

I receive the compile error:

*An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type*

Is there a way to accomplish this task, or am I attempting the impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the `Type` of the resource class as an argument and then use reflections to get the property value.

```
public class DateRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable {
  public DateTime MinimumDate = new DateTime(1901, 1, 1);
  public DateTime MaximumDate = new DateTime(2099, 12, 31);
  private Type _resourceType;

   public DateRangeAttribute(string minDate, string maxDate, string errorMessage, Type resourceType) {
     _resourceType = resourceType;
     var minDateProp = _resourceType.GetProperty(minDate, 
                             BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
     var minDateValue = (string) minDateProp.GetValue((object) null, (object[]) null));
     MinimumDate = DateTime.Parse(minDateValue);

     // similarly get the value for MaxDate

     ErrorMessage = string.Format(errorMessage, 
            MinimumDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), MaximumDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));         
   }
}
```

Eg

```
[DateRange(Resources.MinimumDate, Resources.MaximumDate, "Please enter a date between {0} and {1}", typeof(Resources))]
```

Comment: Awesome!! That helps explain how the standard validation attributes work as well!!  Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You are not attempting the impossible, but you are going to have to work around the limitation just a tad. So, to comply with the compiler we have two options and the first is the most ideal, change the generated `Resources` class.

```
public class Resources {
  public const string PropMinimumDate = "12/15/2010";
  public const string PropMaximumDate = "12/15/2012";
}
```

Now, if we can't do that then we'll go a different route, let's modify the class that the adorned property exists in and add a couple `const` fields to it like so.

```
public class EntityClass
{
    private const string MinimumDate = "12/15/2010";
    private const string MaximumDate = "12/15/2012";

    [DateRange(MinimumDate, MaximumDate, "Please enter a date between {0} and {1}")]
}
```

However, unless you can code generate the entity class the last option kind of violates your need to pull the values from the database. So, hopefully you can change the `Resources` class.